# Bug in multithreaded program (works slowly)

Tags: c, multithreading, time, pthreads

I have to make a multithreaded program(solve a system of equations with method of rotation). My program giving the right answer. But it runs more slowly when i create more threads. Would anyone be able to help me with this?
Part of my code:

```
typedef struct DATA
 {
double *a; 
int n;
int num_thr; 
int total_thr;
int num_row1;
int num_row2;
double cos;
double sin; 
 }  DATA;


 void synchronize(int total_threads)
  {
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t condvar_in = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t condvar_out = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int threads_in = 0;
static int threads_out = 0;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

threads_in++;
if (threads_in >= total_threads)
{
    threads_out = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condvar_in);
} else
    while (threads_in < total_threads)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condvar_in,&mutex);

threads_out++;
if (threads_out >= total_threads)
{
    threads_in = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condvar_out);
} else
    while (threads_out < total_threads)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condvar_out,&mutex);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }

void rotation (double *a,int n, int num_thr,int total_thr,int num_row1,int num_row2,double cos,double sin)
{
int k;
double m;
int first;

first=n-1-num_thr;
for (k=first;k>=num_row1;k=k-total_thr)
{
    m=a[num_row1*n+k];
    a[num_row1*n+k]=cos*a[num_row1*n+k]+sin*a[num_row2*n+k];
    a[num_row2*n+k]=-sin*m+cos*a[num_row2*n+k];

}
    synchronize (total_thr);


 }
void * rotation_threaded(void *pa)
 {

DATA *data=(DATA*)pa ;
rotation(data->a,data->n,data->num_thr,data->total_thr,data->num_row1,data->num_row2,data->cos,data->sin);
return 0;
 }



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
................


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        n1=a[j*n+i];
            m=a[i*n+i];

            cos=m/sqrt(m*m+n1*n1);
            sin=n1/sqrt(m*m+n1*n1);
            for (t=0;t<total_thr;t++)
            {
                data[t].n=n;
                data[t].a=a;
                data[t].total_thr=total_thr;
                data[t].num_thr=t;
                data[t].num_row1=i;
                data[t].num_row2=j;
                data[t].cos=cos;
                data[t].sin=sin;
            }

            for (k=0;k<total_thr;k++)
            {
                if (pthread_create (threads+k,0,rotation_threaded,data+k))                  {
                    printf (" Couldn't create %d thread",k);
                    return 3;
                }

            }
            for (k=0;k<total_thr;k++)
            {

                if (pthread_join (threads[k],0))
                printf ("Mistake %d \n",k);
            }
            h=b[i];
            b[i]=cos*b[i]+sin*b[j];
            b[j]=-sin*h+cos*b[j];
    } 
}

..............
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not have names in the global scope with leading underscore, or names with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter anywhere, as those (and more variants) are reserved by the C specification. When it comes to structures, you can use the same name for both the structure *and* the typedef.

Comment: Also unrelated, but your code could use some formatting. Don't mix indentation with space and tab (as it seems you might have done). And add some comments, so it's easier to follow along what the code does. And when posting to an international site like SO, please try to translate strings and names to English, I doubt many here understands Russian (or related languages).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have the impression that this is far too broad for this site. Do you have a concrete technical question?

Comment: Code without a SINGLE comment; good luck getting help with that.

Comment: Nothing concrete, just don't see why my program works slowly with more threads.

Comment: Just a guess, but the more threads you have, the more they must synchronize with each other, so each thread will spend more time waiting for the other threads than doing any real works.

Comment: Without looking at your code, I'll answer that threading and synchronization can be expensive. It is sometimes faster to do things single-threaded. Even for operations that benefit from parallelism, your hardware may only be able to efficiently handle a certain number of threads (usually number of cores or number of cores x 2 if you have hyperthreading). You also have to take into consideration memory access. If two different threads are trying to access variables that are on the same cache line, you will suffer from [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question: Because your threads spend more time trying to obtain a lock and wait on condition variables than they are doing actual work. Multithreading isn't a free get more power scheme, if you have to constantly acquire highly contended locks you will get a severe overhead penalty for this. The more threads you have, the more they fight over the locks and spend blocked while one other thread holds the lock.

To combat this: Try to only synchronize data when you have to. Queue up a lot of changes, and/or do more work at once to actually leverage the threads time on the CPU. When you synchronize, try to only hold the lock for the shortest absolute necessary time.

Last but not least: More threads may not always be better. If you have multiple threads crunching on a queue of jobs, it's often better to only spin up as many threads as there are logical CPU cores so the threads don't have to fight over the single cores. As with everything though, proper profiling will tell you where the problems are.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you recreate your threads for each `(i,j)` pair, then you wait for all threads to finish.

It would probably make more sense to create your threads at the beginning and have them wait on a condition. The threads could then be reused.

You also seem to be copying a lot of information that is constant for each thread on each iteration (that's probably not the reason for the slowdown but why not make it clear what is variable). The only information in `data` that differs for each thread is `num_thr`. The values of `n` and `a` never changes and the values of `cos`, `sin`, `i` and `j` could be saved outside the `for-t` loop.

What's the use of the `synchronize` method. It seems to wait for all threads to pass the `threads_in` "barrier" then to pass the `threads_out` "barrier" but what is it protecting?